# any approximation for $\sum_{i_3=3}^{n-k+3}\sum_{i_4=i_3+1}^{n-k+4}\sum_{i_5=i_4+1}^{n-k+5}\cdots\sum_{i_k=i_{k-1}+1}^{n} 1, (n \gg k)$?

Tags: approximation, computational-complexity, products

Is there any approximation for

$$\sum\limits_{i_3=3}^{n-k+3}\sum\limits_{i_4=i_3+1}^{n-k+4}\sum\limits_{i_5=i_4+1}^{n-k+5}\cdots\sum\limits_{i_k=i_{k-1}+1}^{n} 1, \quad (n \gg k)$$ ?

We know that $\sum\limits_{i_3=3}^{n-k+3}\sum\limits_{i_4=i_3+1}^{n-k+4}\sum\limits_{i_5=i_4+1}^{n-k+5}\cdots\sum\limits_{i_k=i_{k-1}+1}^{n} 1 <  \sum\limits_{i_3=3}^{n-k+3}\sum\limits_{i_4=4}^{n-k+4}\sum\limits_{i_5=5}^{n-k+5}\cdots\sum\limits_{i_k=k}^{n} 1 = (n-k+1)^{k-2}$

This [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/657162/84247) is related